# Handle exception in EJB

Tags: java, exception, transactions, ejb, ejb-3.0

I have an EJB which performs some DB operation and then call another EJB after JNDI lookup which performs more DB operation. This 2nd EJB call can throw some exceptions i.e. PersistenceException (I looked in the code that this exception marks the transaction as rollbackonly). Is there any way I can avoid rollback of the transaction? Below is the code summarizing the problem. Thank in advance.

```
public class Test {

    ejbMthod1() {
        // This method run under transaction
        // Do some DB operation like update\delete
        if(somecondition) {
            try {
                // JNDI lookup for ejb2
                ejbMethod2();
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                // Will catching the exception here save the Transaction from rollback ?
                // Is there any way I can avoid this rollback just by handling proper exceptions ?
            }
        }   
    }
}

class Test2 {
    ejbMethod2() {
        // Run under same transaction as caller
        // do some DB operation which can throw many exception i.e. PersistenceException.
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: If your problem was solved, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The method that throws the exception must be annotated like:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

There are much more to know about in this subject. I strongly recommend to read [this great article](http://entjavastuff.blogspot.co.id/2011/02/ejb-transaction-management-going-deeper.html?m=1).